# Strawberry Prolog - recursive issue

Tags: prolog

I am new to Prolog and I have an issue using this code of finding if a number is prime.

```
finddivs(N,L) :- helpdivs(N,1,L).

helpdivs(N,I,L) :- I > N. 
helpdivs(N,I,[Lm|Lk]) :- 
  N mod I =:= 0,   
  Lm is I, Ii is I + 1, 
  helpdivs(N,Ii,Lk). 
helpdivs(N,I,L) :- Ii is I+1, helpdivs(N,Ii,L).

takefirst([M|_],M).

length([],0). 
length([_|Lrst],N) :- length(Lrst,N1), N is N1+1.

is_prime(N) :- finddivs(N,L), write(L), nl,
               length(L,P), write(P), nl, P =:= 2.

is_primeh(2).

?- is_prime(4), nl.
```

The result is:

```
.....
3
[1, 2, 4]
3
[1, 2, 4]
3
[1, 2, 4]
3
[1, 2, 4]The program is terminated.
```

I tried `!,fail.` at the end of the function, but still doesn't help.

Can you explain me why this happens?

Comment: One problem: the base case for `is_prime` has a typo: `is_primeh(2).`

Comment: Also, you should not have to supply `length/2` yourself, though yours looks alright.

Comment: Another problem is that your `helpdivs(N,I,[Lm|Lk])` and second `helpdivs(N,I,L)` will trigger as alternative path even if `I > N`. So you need to check for that. In addition, the second `helpdivs(N,I,L)` will trigger as an alternative path even if `N mod I =:= 0` so you need to check for that as well. You might want to consider using an if-then-else construct: `cond -> if_true ; if_false`

Comment: Thank you for your replies! 

@lurker you made my day, helpdivs was triggering the issue! And cond -> is awesome feature!

DanielLyons is_primeh(2). was forgotten by me. It's not a typo, I just forgot to remove it from the final source, I will edit it right now. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To codify this as an answer, the issue with the original implementation is that the predicate `helpdivs` permits Prolog to backtrack into other clauses regardless of the value of `I`.The following implementation will prevent Prolog from backtracking when you don't want it to by constraining the value of `N` in each case:

```
helpdivs(N, I, L) :-
    I > N. 
helpdivs(N, I, [Lm|Lk]) :-
    I =< N,
    N mod I =:= 0,   
    Lm is I, Ii is I + 1, 
    helpdivs(N,Ii,Lk). 
helpdivs(N, I, L) :-
    I =< N,
    N mod I =\= 0,
    Ii is I+1,
    helpdivs(N, Ii, L).
```

To make it a little more DRY, you can use the if-then-else:

```
helpdivs(N, I, _) :-
    I > N.
helpdivs(N, I, L) :-
    I =< N,
    Ii is I + 1,
    (   N mod I =:= 0
    ->  L = [I|Lk],
        helpdivs(N, Ii, Lk)
    ;   helpdivs(N, Ii, L)
    ).
```

There are probably other similar variations on this theme that would work as well.